# Rails I18n pluralization does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I am using rails 4.1.9 with i18n. I want register pluralization rules for Turkish.

This is the pluralizaton.rb under config/initializers

```
require "i18n/backend/pluralization" 
I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Pluralization)
```

And this is the rule in plurals.rb under config/locales.

```
  :tr => { :i18n => { :plural => { :keys => [:one, :other], :rule => lambda { |n| [0, 1].include?(n) ? :one : :other } } } },
```

This is the sample locale file.

```
tr:
 sample:
  one: 1
  other: 3
  zero: 0
```

`I18n.t('sample',count: 0)` is working as expected and retruns `0` but when runnign `I18n.t('sample', count: 1)` gives `3`. How can I build a custom pluralization rules for Turkish? Or where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if you still need the answer, you can try this one!

```
  :tr => { :i18n => { :plural => { :keys => [:zero, :one, :other], :rule => lambda { |n| n == 0 ? :zero : n % 10 == 1 && n % 100 != 11 ? :one : :other } } } }
```

Also you can find many examples here https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/test/test_data/locales/plurals.rb